# Drraggable and droppable elements in a java gui

Tags: java

I'm trying to develop a flow chart designer in Java. To do this I need to have drraggable and droppable elements in the gui. In html/JavaScript this would be relatively trivial however I don't know where to start with java. I've done some searching through the API and can't find native support, however I'm not sure if I'm looking for the wrong things (if that makes sense)?

If this isn't possible natively in java is there anyway to use html/JavaScript/CSS to design a gui for a java back-end? This would solve another question I have about prettfying the standard swing elements (which are pretty ghastly) are there any alternative methods of designing GUIs in java?

Comment: Swing has drag-and-drop support, and you can probably implement dragging of the diagrams, but it will not be very easy. Are you sure it must be in Java?

Comment: It doesn't have to be, what language would you recommend?

Comment: I don't have huge experience with doing GUI, but I'm pretty sure most of the "real world" application that deal with graphics are written in C++ or C#. However, there's another approach - if you make it in javascript / html / css, then all you need is something capable of displaying this content (web view), and you're done. Super easy and cross platform. Just some random ideas, I'm no expert :P